# Generate JAXB classes with initialized fields

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to generate JAXB classes with initialized values. I am generating the JAXB classes from an XSD.

**XSD Definition**

```
<xs:element name="openingBalance" type="xs:decimal" default="0">
```

**Generated JAXB class**

```
@XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "0")
protected BigDecimal openingBalance;
```

**Desired class**

```
@XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "0")
protected BigDecimal openingBalance = BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

Is there a way to generate the JAXB classes such that it is like the desired class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to initialize fields with JAXB generation (default="" works only after unmarshalling).